# Reusing an Exception class for a different purpose

Tags: java, exception

Is it in good practice to use an exception for a different purpose than the intended one, for the name? For example, I wanted an exception something along the lines of "Already exists" and I found the exception "[EntityExistsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html)." The name was great, but it seems it was intended for the `EntityManager`. Is it okay to use the class, or should I create my own?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't reuse an exception unless the package it is in is related to the function you're performing.

Comment: @HotLicks that's the rule of thumb I use, except that if it's in a "generic" package like `java.lang` or `java.util` then it's fair game.

Comment: @IanRoberts - Agreed.

Comment: What happens in situations where an EntityExists could *also* be thrown by the EntityManager for a different reason? How are you going to distinguish the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation. Anyone unfamiliar with your code will look at the exception, and either know its documentation or go and read it.

In this case, the documentation says the exception is

> thrown by the persistence provider when EntityManager.persist(Object)
>   is called

so if it is thrown in other circumstances by your code then your code isn't compatible with the Java API and has a bug.

I would tend to either use or subclass [IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) for your case, since that is a general purpose exception, is widely used, and the state of 'the thing already existing' falls within its specification. If I expected that client code would handle the 'already exists' state differently than other failing states, then I would subclass it, otherwise I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably best answered on a case by case basis, since "different purpose than the intended one" is a little bit vague to offer a complete suggestion on.

In your case, it may come down to a matter of taste.  Personally, unless your already exists exception needs are related to the persistence layer, I would advise against reusing the exception from that package since it is easy to make a new exception and will not confuse any future developers or code that may infer the exception is being passed on from the underlying implementation.